# No integer overflow warning reported in the call to constructor

Tags: c++, clang

I have the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(uint64_t i) { std::cout<<i<<std::endl; }

class A{ 
public:
    A(uint64_t i){ std::cout<<i<<std::endl; } 
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    func(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024ull); // clang [-Winteger-overflow]: Overflow in expression; result is 0 with type 'int'   
    A a(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024ull); // no error
    return 0; 
}
```

I know I should have written `1024ull * 1024 * ...`, but I am wondering why my compiler (clang) only throws the overflow error at the line with func, and is not aware of the problem in the constructor

Comment: g++ 12.1 reports both as warnings; MSVC reports both as well. https://godbolt.org/z/465q6csvd

Comment: This looks like as a godbolt investigation is in good order.  As does g++ 12.2. https://godbolt.org/z/zq9dhvWcr  MSVC gives no warning(but then again it doesn't have a integer overflow check, so that is probably expected.

Comment: Poking around with godbolt.org, it appears that every version of g++ reports both overflows.  This issue/question appears to be specific to clang.

Comment: Interestingly, clang does pass `0` to the constructor (doesn't bother calculating the value, just `xor`s the register), but does not issue the warning.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! OK by typing g++ --version on my mac I got: Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.201). So it seems it is indeed clang's problem. Any ideas whether that is an error or work as designed for clang?

Comment: @royshoo Do note that apple clang, and clang are two different compilers.  Apple is pretty tight lipped about their version.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, No, unsigned overflow is well defined. For signed types it is UB.

Comment: Hi @TeaAgeSolutions, don't we have a signed overflow here?

Comment: @royshoo: Well, is it? There are literals only, and the target is 64 bit unsigned. Aren't the compiler smart enough to automatically choose the greatest necessary type when computing a constant from constants only during compile time? I would expect that. Like, if I write auto i = 4294967296u it will not overflow as uint32 but produce an uint64 for me.

Comment: @TeaAgeSolutions, if you try uint64_t signed_overflow = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; will you see something like "integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]"?

Comment: @TeaAgeSolutions that has nothing to do with the compiler. The compilers are smart, that's why they know that the result overflows. But they can't do anything that the standard doesn't allow. `int*int` produces an `int`, so the compiler can't do `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` in uint64_t even if it knows that the expression overflows

Answer (score 3):

This is slightly simplified your code, where there are two similar signed integer overflows (already in `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`):

```
#include <cstdint>

void func(uint64_t) {}

struct A { 
    A(uint64_t){} 
};

int main() {
    func(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024ull); // warning, ok
    A a(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024ull); // no warning in Clang!
}
```

The one in calling `func` is detected by Clang, GCC and MSVC with appropriate command line options `-Wall -Wextra` for Clang/GCC and `/Wall` for MSVC.

But the other one in calling `A::A` is not detected by Clang. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6vGT33q1W

This is just a Clang bug, which is being fixed right now: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58944